# How reliable is DateTime.UtcNow in Silverlight applications?

Tags: silverlight, datetime, caching, utc

I have a **silverlight** application which users will be running in **various time zones**.

These applications load their data from the server upon start up, then **cache** it in **IsolatedStorage**.

When I make changes to the data on the server, I want to be able to change the "**last updated time**" so that all silverlight clients **download the newest data** the next time they check this date.

However, I'm a bit confused as to how to handle the time zone issue since a if the **server** is in **New York** and the update time is set to **2010-01-01 17:00:00** and a **client** in **Seattle** checks compares it to its local time of **2010-01-01 14:00:00** it won't update and will continue to provide old data for three more hours.

My solution is to always **post** the update time in **UTC time**, not with the time on the server, then make the Silverlight app **check** with **DateTime.UtcNow**.

Is this as easy as it sounds or are their issues with this, e.g. that timezones are not set correctly on computers and hence the SilverlightApp does not report the correct UTC time. **Can anyone say from experience how likely it is that using DateTime.UtcNow like this for cache refreshing will work in all cases?**

If DateTime.UtcNow is not reliable, I will just use an **incremented** "DataVersion" **integer** but there are other scenarios in which getting time zone sychronization down would make it useful to thoroughly understand how to solve this in silverlight apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime.UtcNow is as reliable as the clock on the client system.  So the question is entirely independent of Silverlight or .NET, the question is how much do you trust the system clock on the client machines?

You need to weigh the risk that a user of a machine may have incorrectly set the time on their machine because they have not set the time zone correctly.  This risk is entirely human in nature.

Using an incrementing version number only has one downside, you need to first retrieve the current value before you can set a new one.  If that isn't a problem then go with that and eliminate the FUD you might have around time zones.

Comment: Right, the second approach sounds more certain, perhaps meanwhile it would be interesting to have the silverlight clients send their local times back up to the server and generate reports on how many are off and by how much. It seems you can also get the time zone info with this: System.TimeZoneInfo.Local